# I need to redirect a page when time become 00.00

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I need to wish a birthday to my friend and so I plan to tell my friend to open a webpage @ 11.55 and when time becomes 12.00 I need to automatically redirect my friend's page to my greeting page and help me to do the task

Comment: You could just use javascript to display a message at `00:00`.

Comment: ... or you *could* take him to a strip joint or something out in the real world ......?

Comment: Did you try anything? Any code, any attempt to show?

Comment: ... or just tell to open your greeting page at 12:00 ?

Comment: Do you even have access to "my friend's page"?

Comment: As the js date() depends on the users time, a wrongly set clock could mess up your present :() . If you want a real secure present + good timing start learning http://php.net

Comment: Dear helpers, I created a digital clock to show the current time and another clock that shows remaining time to 12.00 and I developed a surprise website to her and I just told her to open the page that having the digital clock and remaining time clock. when time becomes 12 she should automatically redirect to the surprised website that is my need,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using javascript into the friend's page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function greetings(){
      var now =new Date();
      if (now.getHours()===0 && now.getMinutes()===0) window.location.href='http://google.com';
    }
    setInterval(greetings,10000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks angelito I'll this code

Comment: worked thanks dear  angelito